# Binding parameter to a nested ListView using SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, selecteditem

I'm pretty new to coding in c# and I'm trying on a wpf app to transfer data between different folders.

To visualize the folders and subfolders I've got a tabcontrol with different mainfolders, and under each tab a ListView with information on the subfolders.

All data is gathered in a BindingList 'Klinieken', which is filled with objects 'Kliniek' (mainfolders) which contains objects 'Patient' (subfolders) which is filled with information about said folder. Here is the .xaml file for the mainwindow:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#555555">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="420" />
        <RowDefinition Height="116" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="KliniekTabs" Background="#555555" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10 10 10 10">
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Klinieken}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding BronKliniek}"
                    TabStripPlacement="Top">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding KliniekNaam}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Patienten}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedPatient}">
                        <ListView.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ListView.Resources>
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Patientnaam"
                                                Width="250"
                                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PatientNaam}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Zisnr"
                                                Width="250"
                                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PatientZis}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Aanmaakdatum"
                                                Width="250"
                                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding AanmaakDatum}"/>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="WindowControls" Background="#777777" Grid.Row="1" Margin="100 5 100 10">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Margin="-80 0 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Doel kliniek</Label>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Klinieken}"
                      x:Name="doelKliniekDD"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding DoelKliniek}"
                      Margin="-120 0 0 0" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=KliniekNaam}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20 0 0 0" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Button Height="25" Style="{StaticResource Button_Orange}" Command="{Binding TransferButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=window, Mode=OneWay}"   Margin="0 0 10 0">Transfer</Button>
                <Button Height="25" Style="{StaticResource Button_Orange}" Command="{Binding CopyButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=window, Mode=OneWay}"   Margin="10 0 20 0">Kopieer</Button>
                <Button Height="25" Style="{StaticResource Button_Grey}" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=window, Mode=OneWay}"  Margin="20 0 0 0">Cancel</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And here is the MainViewModel that is referenced in the .xaml:

```
//attributen
string monacoDirectory;
List<string> aanwezigeClinics;
Installation installation;


//constructor
public MainViewModel()
{
    monacoDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["monacoDirectory"];
    

    aanwezigeClinics = new List<string>(Directory.GetDirectories(monacoDirectory, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly));

    aanwezigeClinics.Remove(monacoDirectory + @"\defaults");
    aanwezigeClinics.Remove(monacoDirectory + @"\physics");

    installation = new Installation(aanwezigeClinics);

    Klinieken = new BindingList<Kliniek>();

    foreach (var kliniek in installation.Klinieken)
    {
        Klinieken.Add(kliniek);
    }
}

private Kliniek _doelKliniek;
private Kliniek _bronKliniek;
private Patient _selectedPatient;

private BindingList<Kliniek> _klinieken = new BindingList<Kliniek>();
public BindingList<Kliniek> Klinieken
{
    get { return _klinieken; }
    set { _klinieken = value; }
}

public Kliniek DoelKliniek
{
    get { return _doelKliniek; }
    set
    {
        _doelKliniek = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public Kliniek BronKliniek
{
    get { return _bronKliniek; }
    set
    {
        _bronKliniek = value;

        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public Patient SelectedPatient
{
    get { return _selectedPatient; }
    set
    {
        _selectedPatient = value;
        MessageBox.Show("hoi");
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

The data shows up in the gui just fine, which i was quite happy with. And using SelectedItem on the TabControl and the ComboBox i use later worked out beautifully aswell, but I just cant seem to get the SelectedItem on the ListView to work. I have added a button to test the output of the fields and SelectedPatient always returns as null.

If i check the 'Live Visual Tree' in VS and go to the properties of the ListView i can see the Patient as SelectedItem, so that tells me its not a selection but a binding problem. Furthermore ive tried to google for nested bindings, but the suggestions there didnt change anything about my situation.

Is a nested binding like this possible, or should i take a whole different approach?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem quite a while ago. The suggestions below solved it for me at the time.

Use SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem. This is because SelectedItem doesn't change until the control has been validated. SelectedValue changes whenever the user selects an item. The code you could use is as follows:
`SelectedValue="{Binding BronKliniek, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

For the button part, try to provide `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` instead of `CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=window, Mode=OneWay}"`. This way, you'll get the value of the current DataContext of the button, which you can then use to extract the data you want from this DataContext.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Rob, please, if my answer helped you with your questions please mark my answer as the correct answer. This way you help the community :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it doesnt seem to work for me sadly. 
I've now found a workaround where i seperate the ListView from the TabControl so that it is no longer nested, but i would much rather get this to work.
The weird thing for me is that SelectedItem works perfectly fine for the TabControl and ComboBox, and it shows in the ListView properties that the SelectedItem is filled and changes when i click another item, but I can't get it out